# WPF Since Canvas.SetLeft be used to move items around a canvas in an itemscontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I originally was going to just throw marker classes on the canvas manually in code behind, but then I thought, hmm, I shouldn't really be throwing actual viewobjects into the code inside my view model. So then I thought, "Let me just have a collection and then add to it when i want the View to update."

However, I'm having issues. The problem I am having is that the line I wish to display is not appearing at the desired location.

My goal was to have a small thumb control that I had customized with a template that I could then place in a canvas and use the canvas.setLeft(double) function to set the position of the thumb. This worked fine when I placed it inside a canvas. However, as soon as I switched to the following itemscontrol, instead of displaying the line at the desired location, it always displays the line at coordinate x = 0.

When I call canvas.getleft() on the thumb control, it returns the desired coordinate. However, that is not where it is displaying. I have created a test case to narrow down outside factors and figure out what is going on.

```
 <Application.Resources>

      <Style x:Key="CanvasMarkerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Comp:CanvasMarker}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>


        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Comp:CanvasMarker}">
              <Line 
                Stroke="Orange"
                StrokeThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Comp:CanvasMarker}}, 
                                  Path=StrokeThickness}"
                X1="0"
                Y1="0"
                X2="0"
                Y2="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Comp:CanvasMarker}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>

  </Application.Resources>
```

and the Itemscontrol:

```
 <ItemsControl 
    x:Name="ItemsControl"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Grid.ZIndex="1"
    Background="Gray"
    >
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Canvas 
        x:Name="MarkerCanvas"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="false"
        />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

```
  <Comp:CanvasMarker 
    MarkerTime="50"
    />
</DataTemplate>
```

On Loaded, I take MarkerTime and Canvas.SetLeft(this, MarkerTime);

I feel like there is an obvious reason why I cannot use canvas.setleft. My guess is that it has something to do with how canvas manages its attached properties. I am guessing that it uses them during layout to place the child correctly. I think that maybe in my case where the attached.left property is changed inside an itemspanel, it doesn't prompt another layout or something. Anyway, an explanation or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I figured doing it this way was much more MVVM than just creating view items on a canvas manually from my view model with the correct properties that i desired.

but having a control so I can bind an items collection seems to be more of a headache than i anticipated.

```
public CanvasMarker()
{

  this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(CanvasMarker_Unloaded);
  this.Initialized += new EventHandler(CanvasMarker_Initialized);
  this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(CanvasMarker_Loaded);
  this.DragStarted += new DragStartedEventHandler(CanvasMarker_DragStarted);
  this.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(CanvasMarker_DragDelta);
  this.PreviewMouseDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(CanvasMarker_PreviewMouseDown);
  this.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CanvasMarkerStyle"];
}

void CanvasMarker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  gvvm = Tag as GraphViewerViewModel;
  var p = VisualTreeUtilities.FindParent<DependencyObject>(this);
  var gp = VisualTreeUtilities.FindParent<DependencyObject>(p);
  var ggp = VisualTreeUtilities.FindParent<DependencyObject>(gp);
  var gggp = VisualTreeUtilities.FindParent<DependencyObject>(ggp);
  ParentCanvas = VisualTreeUtilities.FindParent<Canvas>(this) as Canvas;

  double MarkerHorizontalPositionInPixels = MarkerTime / gvvm.UnitsOfTimePerPixel;
  SetMarker(MarkerHorizontalPositionInPixels);

}


void CanvasMarker_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}

void CanvasMarker_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

static void SetMarkerToNewPosition(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

  CanvasMarker cm = d as CanvasMarker;
  if (cm.IsLoaded)
  {
    double MarkerHorizontalPositionInPixels = cm.MarkerTime / cm.gvvm.UnitsOfTimePerPixel;
    cm.SetMarker(MarkerHorizontalPositionInPixels);
    if (cm.IsCurrentMarker)
    {
      cm.gvvm.MarkerExists = true;
      cm.gvvm.CalculateValuesAtPrimaryMarker();
    }
  }
}

void CanvasMarker_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}

void CanvasMarker_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
  double NewXPosition = XPositionInPixels + e.HorizontalChange;
  SetMarker(NewXPosition);
}


void SetMarker(double PositionInPixels)
{
  if (PositionInPixels < StrokeThickness / 2)
  {
    PositionInPixels = StrokeThickness / 2;
  }
  else if (PositionInPixels > ParentCanvas.ActualWidth)
  {
    PositionInPixels = ParentCanvas.ActualWidth;
  }
  Canvas.SetLeft(this, PositionInPixels);
  double d = Canvas.GetLeft(this);
  XPositionInPixels = PositionInPixels;

}
void CanvasMarker_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem but if you use `ItemsControl` each item will placed within `ContentControl` and if you want to set `Canvas.Top` and/or `Canvas.Left` you need to do it on that element via `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`

Comment: so can I set canvas.top from the code behind of the canvas marker class? It's strange that it doesn't seem to get applied; I would use the itemcontainerstyle, but my goal was to be able to update the canvas position on drag, but i'm not sure exactly how i would do this with the style. I will post some more of the code

Comment: It's much easier to do it through style but you can still do it in code but you need to find correct content control by going through visual tree.

Comment: so the issue then is just that i need to call canvas.setleft on the contentpresenter hosting the Marker rather than on the marker itself?

I'm fine with either way, but what is the datacontext of the itemcontainer style? is it the datacontext of the itemscontrol or the datacontext of the item? I will play with it. at the very least it seems that this can solve my issue so thanks

Comment: Basically you need to set `Canvas.Left`/`Canvas.Top` on the item which is put directly on `Canvas`, in case of `ItemsControl` it will be `ContentPresenter`. Since you're setting style for content container so same context will apply, which will be your item. You can bind `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` to properties of your view model.

Comment: so that seems to work. I'm lazy so I didn't want to create an extra view model for the items control just to be able to bind the property i want (if i had .net 4.0 i could use x:reference to bind, but for now i think it's easier to just do in code behind. One thing I can't figure out though is how to get the canvas that is in my itemspaneltemplate, so i think i will create a new question for that thanks for your help